# How to attach pyautogui to the virtual display?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyautogui, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

How do I attach `pyautogui` to the display in multithreaded mode?

In the example of my code, `pyautogui` always has access to the upper display.

Is it possible to have `pyautogui` control on each display?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import Xlib.display
# ...

# let's say i run this function in two threads
def do_work(data):
    v_display = Display(visible=0, size=(900, 600))
    v_display.start()

    # How can i attach v_display to the pyautogui?
    import pyautogui

    print(v_display)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798478/how-i-can-attach-the-mouse-movement-pyautogui-to-pyvirtualdisplay-with-seleniu
    pyautogui._pyautogui_x11._display = Xlib.display.Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

    print(pyautogui._pyautogui_x11._display)

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+str(data['profile']))
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")


    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

    driver.get('https://my_resource.co/?'+data['param'])


    pyautogui.click(x=880, y=580)
    # Click always goes through the upper display
    # I also tried to take screenshots they are always the same

    # ...

    driver.quit()
    v_display.stop()
```

Output:

```
<Display cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '900x600x24', ':1086'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '900x600x24', ':1086'] oserror=None return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
<Display cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '900x600x24', ':1087'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-br', '-nolisten', 'tcp', '-screen', '0', '900x600x24', ':1087'] oserror=None return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
<Xlib.display.Display object at 0x7f4f5493aa90>
<Xlib.display.Display object at 0x7f4f5493a8d0>
```

P.S.
I know how to make clicks through `selenium`, but I need exactly `pyautogui` events.

Comment: [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13607672) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66085601) saying "Well, what about this source? https://abhishekvaid13.medium.com/pyautogui-headless-docker-mode-without-display-in-python-480480599fc4 (need to have at least 30 chars!!)"

Comment: Thanks Scratte - big debate with admin team who kept hiding / deleting my post on the premise the link may change - despite the fact that I archived the page in 'Wayback Chrome'.  Latest below doesn't seem to be causing them too much fuss-  so all good for now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pyautogui documentation at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ :

```
Q: Does PyAutoGUI work on multi-monitor setups.
A: No, right now PyAutoGUI only handles the primary monitor.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky to do - but there are some ingenious workarounds:

Thanks to [Abhishek Vaid](http://web.archive.org/web/20210216014644/https://abhishekvaid13.medium.com/pyautogui-headless-docker-mode-without-display-in-python-480480599fc4):

"*To run PYAUTOGUI headless you will need to make a docker using Xdisplay and provide path to virtual display to PYAUTOGUI to do so. Basically it will have the display memory run in the backend without actually having a display. Server deployable.*"

Hope this works for you (code can be found at link above, I haven't tested though)...